# Does upgrading your sword help if you have full life?

Tags: 3d-dot-game-heroes

I've upgraded my first upgradable sword some, and I can't notice much difference. The pixelated one that you have when you're hurt looks very upgradable, but the giant one seems to look the same, even if I have a wood sword.

Does upgrading improve both, or is the giant one just the best that it can be? What if I change weapons and buy the Claymore from that guy in the middle of nowhere, would the fully-healed version be better then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading only applies to a full health sword. Might not be as noticeable but each star will give it more length/size/damage.

Also, each sword has different aspects that can be upgraded. Really without following a guide your best bet is just to stick to one sword that you upgrade until you find a lot more powerful one.

Comment: Cool, time to look for a guide then. ;)

Comment: Worth it either way, really fun game. :]